# Off Center Studs for TV Mount, No Third Stud Available

Tags: mounting

We are hanging a larger tv on our mantel. We previously had a 50" tv where we are not mounting a 70" tv (62 pounds). The wall only has two studs (24" spacing) that are off center to the left. Our existing mounting plate was not wide enough for the stud spacing, so I have purchased another mount with a 37" plate. The problem is, because of the VESA spacing on the back of the new tv, in order for the tv to be centered to the wall, the mounting clips attached to the tv will have to rest pretty far to the right side of mounting plate. The right clip will actually have to sit out past the stud to the right. The mount is rated for 165 pounds, but I'm worried about all the weight loading on the right side of the plate. Is there another way to go about this? Should I just add some toggle bolts to the right side of the plate? See the attached diagram for a visual.

[image]

Comment: Standard answer (I'll look for an official "duplicate"): Mount plywood to the two studs and large enough for the entire bracket. Paint it to approximately match the wall (exact shade doesn't matter as it will be mostly hidden by the TV). Attach the bracket to the plywood. Done.

Comment: And toggle bolts don't do a whole lot. They *can* if the drywall is in perfect shape and the toggles are installed well. Or if they are in metal studs (which is an entirely different installation question). But when you have wood studs, just add plywood and you're done.

Comment: Also check the mounting instructions - they may have an indication of how far off "center" and studs the mount can be.

Comment: `so I have purchased another mount with a 37" plate` I would check the weight rating on the plate. As a mechanical engineer myself, what you're describing is what I would imagine they would be using as the edge case for designing the part - "Can we put the maximum load at the maximally adjusted position?" Even if you had 16 inch stud spacing, the fact that they made it 37 inches wide says to me that they purposefully designed it to not bolt into three studs. If you're at all concerned I would think you'd get a definitive answer, and faster, if you reached out to the manufacturer.

Answer (score 1):

The brackets I've used have multiple hole locations so they don't have to be centered on the studs. You should probably check that first to see if the needed flexibility is already there. Two studs is probably sufficient even if off-center. Check the mount's instructions. Or check if another mount will do what you need.

If not, then as others have said you can put bridging material such as plywood across several sides, sized to let you mount the bracket where you want it. This can be completely hidden behind the set, and if painted to match either the wall or the mount and set doesn't look unreasonable.

I would definitely want screws in at least one stud, for safety. Earthquakes can be felt in unexpected places, sometimes

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue.

Mark the holes where the bracket will hit the studs and 2 extra holes to the right where the weight of the TV will hang.

Install [Drywall anchors](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09P4JPFB8) in the 2 holes that don't hit studs. Use the bigger ones that hold 75 or even 100lbs.

Mount the bracket to the wall with 4 lag bolts (5/16x 2 to 3") These are usually supplied in the kit.  Predrill the holes for the bolts. with a 5/32nds bit.

Install screws with washers into the drywall anchors.

This will give enough support for most any TV.  I have done quite a few this way. It is rare that the studs line up in just the right place.